# Pass multiple coordinates to maps.googleapis.com

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I want to retrieve the elevation of some coordinates using Google Maps API from Xcode project.
I can retrieve the data for one point, but when I try to pass multiple coordinates in the url request I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

My code is the following:

```
-(void) queryGooglePlaces {

    //WORKS FINE PASSING ONLY ONE POINT --->
    NSString *url = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=36.578581,-118.291994&sensor=false";

    //FAIL WHEN I PASS MORE THAN ONE POINT --->
    //NSString *url = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=36.578581,-118.291994|36.23998,-116.83171&sensor=false";

    //Formulate the string as a URL object.
    NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

    // Retrieve the results of the URL.
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;

    //THE CODE CRASHES HERE ---->
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

    NSArray* places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];  
}
```

I don't know what is the problem. The syntax looks correct following the guidelines of Google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself,

adding the following statement below the declaration of the url variable the problem has been solved:

```
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I think the character pipeline was generating a problem, with this instruction you encode your NSString by adding percent escapes to provide a valid url.

Best regards!